# How to convert or round numbers like `-7.5E+37`

Tags: php

It might include a general math question.

I am using Math calculation library trader

[trader_stddev](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.trader-stddev.php) function returns like `-7.5E+37`

I need to round this for mor simple percentage.

```
round($number,2)
```

doesn't work.

How can I make it ? and How do you call this `E` ??( I would like to google around about this E but I am not sure how to call this)

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: Start here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is scientific notation. The `e` stands for *exponent* or the [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation), and this is how PHP reports extremely large (or extremely small) numbers. So your number is actually `-7.5 x (10^37)`.

Instead of `round()`, you can use `number_format()` to get what you need:

```
number_format($number, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

E is exponential function, a shortcut in computer to imply a power that the number `10` is raised into then be multiplied to the number that means the output is actually

> -7.5x(10^37).

Comment: Thanks , I understood the meaning of E